# Unable to remove the Ripple effect using LocalRippleTheme on Pixel 6 Pro with API 33

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using Pixel 6 Pro with API 32 and 34, I was able to successfully remove the Ripple effect. However, it doesn't work on API 33. Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Thanks.

```
MyTheme {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme
    ) {
        MainView()
    }
}

@Stable
object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor(): Color = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha() = RippleAlpha(
        draggedAlpha = 0.0f,
        focusedAlpha = 0.0f,
        hoveredAlpha = 0.0f,
        pressedAlpha = 0.0f
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample you provided is correct and it should work on all `OS` versions.
First of all, `Color.Unspecified` / `Color.Transparent` are ignored on all devices regardlees of `OS` version so the removal of the ripple effect stems entirely from the ***0%*** opacity you have provided.

However, according to the `Android` documentation:

> API 33: There is a bug where the ripple is clamped to a minimum of 0.5, instead of a maximum like before - this should be resolved in future versions

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ripple/RippleAlpha)

**There doesn't seem to be anything** we can do to change the alpha (quite unfortunate really as most `OS` bugs are).

So if the alpha is fixed in place, the only way we can adjust the appearance of the ripple is through the colour. Usually, either ***Black*** or ***White*** would be used as a base and the transparency will be used to achieve the final tone. As it stands, the **opacity** is **fixed** in place so instead of using ***Black*** with ***10%*** opacity, one can use a lighter colour so that in combination with the ***24% opacity***, the same end effect is achieved.

*TLDR: The `RippleAlpha` is ignored on `API 33` and the only way to achieve a lighter ripple is to use a ligther colour as a base*